# How to insert a footnote of author affiliation?

Tags: footnotes, affiliation, author, ieeeconf

I am using document class `ieeeconf` to write a paper. How should I include a footnote indicating author affiliations? Please guide.

Comment: read package documentation. in it this is described.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use `\author{ Author Name \thanks{Affiliation} }`

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEconf}


\begin{document}

    \title{Development of a Generalized PV Model in MATLAB/Simulink Using Datasheet Values}


\author{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh
            \thanks{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh is with the Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, North Dakota State University, Fargo, ND, 58102 USA. email: almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu}
        }

    \maketitle


\begin{abstract}

This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```